# How to pass json object data using Gson?

Tags: android, parcelable

i know there is lots of solution available but none of them help me i am parsing json data data using Gson, and i want to parse this data to another activity as well but i am getting null pointer exception on that.

```
 RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
    JsonObjectRequest jsOnbjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.MyProfile,
            userProfile,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {
                //    Toast.makeText(mContext, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Gson mGson=new Gson();
                    mMyProfile=mGson.fromJson(response.toString(),MyProfile.class);
                    firstNameView.setText(mMyProfile.getMyProfileDTO().get(0).getFirstName());
                    lashNameView.setText(mMyProfile.getMyProfileDTO().get(0).getLastName());
                    adressNameView.setText(mMyProfile.getMyProfileDTO().get(0).getAddress());
                    countryNameView.setText(mMyProfile.getMyProfileDTO().get(0).getCountry());
                    zipCodeView.setText(mMyProfile.getMyProfileDTO().get(0).getZipCode());
                    emailIdView.setText(mMyProfile.getMyProfileDTO().get(0).getEmail());
                    phonNoview.setText(mMyProfile.getMyProfileDTO().get(0).getPhoneNumber());



                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "ErrorMsg" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });
    requestQueue.add(jsOnbjRequest);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit_profile, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_edit:
            if (Connectivity.isConnected(mContext))
            {

                /*Intent userEditProfile = new Intent(mContext, EditProfileActivity.class);
                userEditProfile.putExtra("userProfile",mMyProfile);
                startActivity(userEditProfile);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left,
                        R.anim.left_to_right);*/
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), EditProfileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("profile ", mMyProfile);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                Connectivity.showNoConnection(mContext);
            }

            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

while parsing this data i am not able to get parsing object on that my next Activity is like:

```
 MyProfile object = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("profile");
        userFirstName=object.getMyProfileDTO().get(0).getFirstName();
```

and log cat point on bean  class:

```
 public class MyProfile implements Parcelable
{

@SerializedName("Status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("Message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("myProfileDTO")
@Expose
private List<MyProfileDTO> myProfileDTO = null;
public final static Parcelable.Creator<MyProfile> CREATOR = new 
Creator<MyProfile>() {


    @SuppressWarnings({
            "unchecked"
    })
    public MyProfile createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyProfile(in);
    }

    public MyProfile[] newArray(int size) {
        return (new MyProfile[size]);
    }

   }
        ;

  protected MyProfile(Parcel in) {
    this.status = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
    this.message = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
    in.readList(this.myProfileDTO, 
 (MyProfileDTO.class.getClassLoader()));//here null pointer exception 
 }

 public MyProfile() {
 }

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public List<MyProfileDTO> getMyProfileDTO() {
    return myProfileDTO;
}

public void setMyProfileDTO(List<MyProfileDTO> myProfileDTO) {
    this.myProfileDTO = myProfileDTO;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeValue(status);
    dest.writeValue(message);
    dest.writeList(myProfileDTO);
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `MyProfile.class` implement `Serializable`

make sure your response is in `json` format and then in  onResponse() of volley use `GsonBuilder()` like this

```
MyProfile myprofile = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(response.toString(), MyProfile .class);
```

then start activity with intent

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("myprofileObject", myprofile );
startActivity(i);
```

and receive the object in `NextActivity.class` like this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
MyProfile myprofile = (MyProfile )intent .getSerializableExtra("myprofileObject");
```

If you implement your class as **Parcelable** then receive the object in `NextActivity.class` like this

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    MyProfile myprofile = (MyProfile )intent .getParcelableExtra("myprofileObject");
```

Comment: when are you starting new activity?

Comment: should i change my bean class?

Comment: No but are your starting new activity after you get data from the volley response?? If you start activity before you get data then it may produce null pointer exception. And also check if you are getting data in response or not. Any way my code must work fine unless the response is Null.

Answer (score 3):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyProfile obj = new MyProfile();
String jsonInString = gson.toJson(obj);
// pass string object to next activity and convert string object to class.
//next activity write this code.
MyProfile obj= gson.fromJson(jsonInString, MyProfile.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing MyProfile Object as Parcelable, try as below in the sender class:

```
String data = new Gson().toJson(mMyProfile);

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), EditProfileActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("profile ", data);
            startActivity(intent);
```

At Receiver class, get your profile info as below:

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("profile");

MyProfile object = new Gson().fromJson(data,MyProfile.class)
```

This might work for your case.

Comment: i used Parcelable because is 10X faster  in Serializeable  what about that

Comment: I agree your point, But can you tell me what is your exception message?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: In data class, try List.class.getClassLoader() instead of MyProfileDTO.class.getClassLoader(). and let me know that's you are facing

Comment: Kishor Data is delver form main activity but am not able to get data in second activity with null Pointer exception

Comment: are you preserving list of Profiles into single Profile Model?

Comment: can you please elaborate  my code on that scenario i did not get properly

Comment: String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("profile");

            MyProfile object = new Gson().fromJson(data,MyProfile.class)
            userFirstName=object.getMyProfileDTO().get(0).getFirstName();
            userLastName=object.getMyProfileDTO().get(0).getLastName();
            userAdress=object.getMyProfileDTO().get(0).getAddress();
            userCountry=object.getMyProfileDTO().get(0).getCountry();
            userZipCode=object.getMyProfileDTO().get(0).getZipCode();
            userEmail=object.getMyProfileDTO().get(0).getEmail();

Comment: My Question is about this line  List<MyProfileDTO> myProfileDTO = null;

Comment: userLastName=object.getMyProfileDTO().get(1).getLastName(); userAdress=object.getMyProfileDTO().get(1).getAddress(); userCountry=object.getMyProfileDTO().get(1).getCountry(); userZipCode=object.getMyProfileDTO().get(1).getZipCode(); userEmail=object.getMyProfileDTO().get(1).getEmail();                    this can also be happens right? I mean, your MyProfile POJO class can also store n number of profiles too.

Comment: in `onOptionsItemSelected()` check if `myProfile` object is null using Log.d()

Comment: Farhan in sender  class i am able to get message object like that  firstName,lastName after sending the receiver activity am getting null object.

Comment: Ok, try this, list = in.readArrayList(MyProfileDTO.class.getClassLoader()), also make MyProfileDTO also a parcelable