# gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra() returns null

Tags: android, string, android-intent, gson

I am sending object from `SurfaceInspectionListActivity` to `AddSurfaceInspectionActivity`

on putExtra I can see the data in debug mode but while retrieving data I am getting NULL

I tried to fetch it as String for the test that too results in NULL

```
surfaceObjString = getIntent().getStringExtra("myjsonSurfaceObject2");
```

**Here is the `SurfaceInspectionListActivity` Intent code**

```
public void addSurfaceInspection(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(SurfaceInspectionListActivity.this, AddSurfaceInspectionActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("myjsonSurfaceObject2", surfaceObject);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

**Here is the retrieval code on  `AddSurfaceInspectionActivity`**

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
        surfaceObj = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("myjsonSurfaceObject2"), Surfaces.class);
```

Comment: Checkt his link out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530864/how-to-pass-json-object-data-using-gson

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
public void addSurfaceInspection(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(SurfaceInspectionListActivity.this, AddSurfaceInspectionActivity.class);
     Gson gson = new Gson();
   String sruface = gson.toJson(surfaceObject, Surfaces.class);
    intent.putExtra("myjsonSurfaceObject2", sruface );
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: didn't worked crashed before starting the next activity

Comment: Show the logcat

Comment: @YashKrishanVerma . 

Expected receiver of type in.gov.bihar.minorirrigation.mwrd.mwrd.db.entity.Surfaces, but got java.lang.String

Comment: I've added my answer, kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

First make `Surfaces` `Serializable` by implement `Serializable` interface. And then change `SurfaceInspectionListActivity`:

```
public void addSurfaceInspection(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(SurfaceInspectionListActivity.this, AddSurfaceInspectionActivity.class);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("myjsonSurfaceObject2", surfaceObject);

    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

In order to `Surface` object in `AddSurfaceInspectionActivity`:

```
Surface surface = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myjsonSurfaceObject2");
```

Comment: public class Surfaces implements Serializable
already there tried this code .. didn't crashed but object is NULL on the other activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Convert your object to JSON using  Gson
2. Pass it to activity
3. In SurfaceInspectionListActivity, convert it back to object using Gson

   ```
   public void addSurfaceInspection(View view) {

   Intent intent = new Intent(SurfaceInspectionListActivity.this, AddSurfaceInspectionActivity.class);
   //Convert to string
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String json = gson.toJson(surfaceObject);
   intent.putStringExtra("myjsonSurfaceObject2", json);
   startActivity(intent);
   finish();
   }
   ```

In `AddSurfaceInspectionActivity`:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 surfaceObj = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("myjsonSurfaceObject2"), Surfaces.class);
```

Comment: what is "user" here ?

Comment: App crashes before starting activity 

logCat

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type in.gov.bihar.minorirrigation.mwrd.mwrd.db.entity.Surfaces, but got java.lang.String
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Native Method)

Comment: ok instead of putExtra use putStringExtra, i've added in answer

Comment: Did you try using putstringextra?

Comment: intent.putStringExtra

is giving error not recognized by IDE

Comment: share that logcat output

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using an object with `Serializable` implemented, you don't need to use Gson anymore. Just use `putExtra()` and `getExtra()`. Something like this:

```
// there is nothing need to be changed here.
public void addSurfaceInspection(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SurfaceInspectionListActivity.this, AddSurfaceInspectionActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("myjsonSurfaceObject2", surfaceObject);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Then get the object with:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtra();
surfaceObj = (Surfaces) bundle.getSerializable("myjsonSurfaceObject2");
```

---

If **Gson** is your prerequisite, then you can use something like this:

```
 // get the String of object
public static String convertToGsonString(Surface surfaceObject) {
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  return gson.toJson(surfaceObject);
}

// convert to object from String
public static Surface convertToObjectFromString(String objString) {
  Type type = new TypeToken<Surface>() {}.getType();

  Gson gson = new Gson();
  return gson.fromJson(objString, type);
}
```

Then you can use the above methods to send the intent:

```
public void addSurfaceInspection(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SurfaceInspectionListActivity.this, AddSurfaceInspectionActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("myjsonSurfaceObject2", convertToGsonString(surfaceObject));
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

then receive it:

```
 Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtra();
 String objString = extra.getString("myjsonSurfaceObject2");

 surfaceObj = convertToObjectFromString(objString);
```

Please be noted that you don't need to use Serializable when using Gson.

Comment: intent.getExtra();   // gave error 

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        surfaceObj = (Surfaces) bundle.getSerializable("myjsonSurfaceObject2");

tried this but still got NULL

Comment: You need to check if you have an extra. Do something like this:  
`Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle.has("myjsonSurfaceObject2")) {
    // process extra here.
} else {
   // Not found any extra here!!!
}`

Comment: The problem usually because you give an incorrect key for the extra.

Comment: intent.putExtra("myjsonSurfaceObject2", surfaceObject);


Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
surfaceObj = (Surfaces) bundle.getSerializable("myjsonSurfaceObject2");

Didn't worked